# Drive not showing up

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

Just to make it clear from the start: I have absolutely no in depth knowledge of windows.
I got this company computer with windows 7 on it that was in a domain. It starts up fine but I can't login because the computer is not connected to the domain anymore.
My idea was to get the hard drive, put it in a external hdd interface and connect it to my laptop, recover the windows key with ProduKey (worked for me in the past) and just reinstall windows on the company pc. But when I try to connect the hdd it doesn't show up in the explorer and not even when I list the disks in diskpart. It just shows up in the diskmanager but it displays a storage capacity of 16TB (it's a 500gb hdd).
Can anybody give me any advice on how to get the windows working on that machine?
[image]

Comment: Strange that it shows up as 16tb. That might be an issue with your drive bay. Or it could be some type of full disk encryption. If the drive is encrypted you will not be able to do what you want. Boot the original system from a windows installation disk and see if you can use the command prompt in recovery options to access the drive. This will tell you if it is a hardware (drive bay) issue or an encryption issue. Use `diskpart` to get more info about the status of the drive.

Comment: @lorenz have you removed the battery and looked for the windows COA there?

Comment: @shawn sadly I didn't find a sticker with the key on it (it's a desktop pc so there is no battery) but thx anyways

Comment: @Appleoddity Ok I did what you suggested and the disk shows up with the correct size when I list all disks. I tried to put it directly into another computer as well but I couldn't get windows to boot from the original drive (couldn't configure boot order because I had to deactivate safe boot and couldn't find where to deactivate it) and it would always boot from the disk I'm trying to recover the key from.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm using the drive bay regularly with other drives and it always worked fine till now by the way.

Comment: I’m not fully following your response. What did you do that I suggested when you saw it show up correctly? If another computer is trying to boot the drive then it definitely sounds like the problem is your bay or your computer you’re plugging it in to. I would just work around the problem in some other way. Use a boot disk like I suggested. You don’t need the drive bay or another computer. You can do what you want with a boot disk.

Comment: Another option would be to run something like produkey to read the tattoo if it has one. You'll need to boot from a live distro and run it.